# NoSuchMethodError after successful Login at Microsoft Azure Active Directory and while redirecting to Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate **Spring Boot** with **azure active directory** for authentication. SpringBoot application started successfully and it is redirecting to Azure AD login page and login also successful but while redirecting to my spring boot application getting below error and flow stopping at Microsoft login page as attached.

I am not sure if it is due to jar conflicts or configuration issue. Could someone guide me in right path to resolve this issue please.

```
I am using below dependencies:

    spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.5.0
    azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory - 3.5.0
    spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.0.jar
```

[image]

```
2021-11-18 13:42:53.308 ERROR 10380 --- [nio-8586-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/supervisor] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/endpoint/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest;)Lorg/springframework/http/RequestEntity;
    at com.azure.spring.common.AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:30)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:29)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:16)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:77)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getResponse(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADHandleConditionalAccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AADHandleConditionalAccessFilter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried to skip for now and continue?

Comment: After I click on Skip for now I am getting attached ERROR and screen is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` majorly occurs due to version conflicts of dependencies ,as few methods or libraries in some cases maynot be compatible or maynot be present.
And this can be worked around by upgrading the dependent versions or even by downgrading them when required .Sometimes, even by removing the dependencies which are not necessary in some use cases.

The issue was resolved  by downgrading the  spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.4.12 as  spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.0.jar doesn't have OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert method having transitive dependency for spring-boot-starter-parent as updated by @IamVenkatReddy.

> Please **note** that ,if any issues occur or when suspected attacks
> seems to be likely ,it is recommended  to use Spring Boot Starter for
> Azure Active Directory version greater than 3.6.1   as Spring Security
> versions ex:5.5.x prior to 5.5.1 are susceptible for Denial of service
> attacks

Reference Note in  [spring boot starter for azure-active-directory developer-guide | Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide)